# PHP filesize() showing old filesize with a file inside a windows shared (network) folder

Tags: php, apache, file-get-contents, filesize

I have the following script that runs to read new content from a file:

```
<?php
clearstatcache();
$fileURL = "\\\\saturn\extern\seq_ws.csv";
$fileAvailable = file_exists($fileURL);
$bytesRead = file_get_contents("bytes.txt");

if($fileAvailable){
    $fileSize = filesize($fileURL);
    //Statusses 1 = Partial read, 2 = Complete read, 0 = No read, -1 File not found. followed by !!
    if($bytesRead < $fileSize){
        //$bytesRead till $fileSize bytes read from file.
        $content = file_get_contents($fileURL, NULL, NULL, $bytesRead);
        file_put_contents("bytes.txt", ((int)$bytesRead + strlen($content)));
        echo "1!!$content";
    }else if($bytesRead > $fileSize){
        //File edit or delete detected, whole file read again.
        $content = file_get_contents($fileURL);
        file_put_contents("bytes.txt", strlen($content));
        echo "2!!$content";
    }else if($bytesRead == $fileSize){
        //No new data found, no action taken.
        echo "0!!";
    }
}else{
    //File delete detected, reading whole file when available
    echo "-1!!";
    file_put_contents("bytes.txt", "0");
}
?>
```

It works perfect when I run it and does what is expected. 
When I edit the file from the same PC and my server it works instantly and returns the correct values. 
However when I edit the file from another PC, my script takes about 4-6 seconds to read the correct filesize of the file.

I added `clearstatcache();` on top of my script, because I think its a caching issue. But the strange thing is that when I change the file from the server PC it responds instantly, but from another it doesn't.

On top of that as soon as the other PC changes the file, I see the file change in Windows with the `filesize` and content but for some reason, it takes Apache about 4-6 seconds to detect the change. In those 4-6 seconds it receives the old `filesize` from before the change.

So I have the following questions:

1. Is the `filesize` information cached anywhere maybe either on the Apache server or inside Windows?
2. If question 1 applies, is there anyway to remove or disable this caching?
3. Is it possible this isnt a caching problem?

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filesize.php read the NOTE part: `Note: The results of this function are cached. See clearstatcache() for more details.`

Comment: I think on Your local dev environment php.ini has lower `realpath_cache_ttl` param.

Comment: @num8er im already using `clearstatcache()` as you can see in my script. the problem is more complicated than that cause it involves a UNC location. Also `clearstatcache()` is used mostly(if not always) for calls to the same file inside a script. My problem lies with each call of the script. But thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I think that in Your local PC php has development settings.

So I suggest to check php.ini for [this param](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.realpath-cache-ttl): `realpath_cache_ttl`

Which is:

```
realpath_cache_ttl integer
```

> Duration of time (in seconds) for which to cache realpath 
>   information for a given file or directory. 
>   For systems with rarely changing files, 
>   consider increasing the value.

to test it, php info both locally and on server to check that value:

```php
<?php phpinfo();
```